# How to multithread an array update?

Tags: multithreading, math, rust, parallel-processing

I have a vector of particles in rust

`let particles = Vec<Particle>::new();`

These particles can collide, so I need to push them apart. Right now I am pushing them apart using a grid acceleration lookup in a single thread. I.e. for each particle find the particles in adjacent cells and then compute pushing forces against all of them.

I want to parallelize it, which at a high level would mean:

- Create an array of atomic booleans, one boolean per particle.
- Spawn k threads
- Split the particle array into k equally sized subintervals
- Each thread computes which particles indices it's about to update
- THREAD WAITS ON THE BOOLEANS FOR THOSE INDICES.
- Threads acquire, update and release their indices by writing to the atomic boolean array.

My current challenge is, I don't know how to actually code this because of rust's borrowing rules. I need k different mutable handles to the atomic array, otherwise I cannot both read and write to it to check if things are ok.

What do I do?

Comment: Use interior mutability, e.g. a `Vec<Mutex<Particle>>` or `Vec<RwLock<Particle>>`

Comment: oof... I guess there might not be a better solution

Comment: If you can somehow split the work so that all threads get different, disjoint parts of the `Vec` you might be able to make use of [`get_many_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.get_many_mut) though it is not stable at the moment.

Comment: Are the subintervals contiguous? If yes, you can use `split_at_mut()`.